# ListView - can't cast intent on TextView

Tags: java, android, list, android-intent, youtube

I have problem with my app. For first,i'll explain how it should work. App using ListView when user click on TextView it should move user from app to youtube (for example,to see music video of favorite song) the problem is where user tap on TextView,just nothing happened,what should i change in my code?

*For now,i won't pass the link to youtube by class which should add data to list,for now,i just want to make it step by step,and i just created String with link to video.

Constructor class

```
package com.example.kacper.recyclerview;

public class Constructor {
private String mYoutubeLink;

public Constructor (String youtubeLink){
    mYoutubeLink = youtubeLink;
}

 public String getYoutubeLink(){return mYoutubeLink;}
}
```

Adapter class

```
package com.example.kacper.recyclerview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Constructor> {
private Context context;
String id = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGwWNGJdvx8&list=RD87gWaABqGYs&index=4";

public Adapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Constructor> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View list = convertView;
    if (list == null) {
        list = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.TextView123);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + id));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return list;
}
```

}

Class which will contain data and add it to list someday.. :D

```
package com.example.kacper.recyclerview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class empty extends AppCompatActivity {
String string;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    ArrayList<Constructor> list = new ArrayList<Constructor>();
    list.add(new Constructor("dummy data"));
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, list);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

activity_list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView123"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_list_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Comment: post the code of R.layout.activity_list_item please

Comment: I just edited post. You can see it now.

Comment: It seem to me that the clickable view is quite small, try increase the size of textview and then try again. set let's say 100dp width and put a specific height

Comment: Still nothing happened.

Comment: So.. Any ideas how to make it work? :)

Comment: There nothing wrong as far as we can see. if you can post your sample code as project i will look into it.

Comment: Sure,here's the code https://github.com/Witt3312/Demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing your code, it seems that your Adapter constructor needs to be changed to

```
public Adapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Constructor> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);
    this.context = context;
}
```

The context is null in below code and thus giving `NullPointerException`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + id));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

You should also adhere to [Android Coding style guidelines](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/code-style)

Answer (score 0):

I can't give an exact answer, but I would recommend setting breakpoints in the getView and onClick methods to see what's actually being called. It's hard to diagnose the problem if you don't know where the issue is. You might have an issue with your ListView which is causing the adapter to not get called, or an issue with the way you're firing the intent. If you think it's the intent I'd recommend just firing the intent in the onCreate method of your Activity.

Comment: Ok i'll try to do something with those methods. :)